Open-RMF Plugin Error
I am learning Open-RMF and have been trying to create my own demo.
So far I did everything right but cannot integrate the slotcar plugin, which is used to navigate the robot to locations in the Gazebo. The error is:
[gzclient-18] Topic [/data://world/world/model/DeliveryRobot/plugin/slotcar/joint_cmd] is not valid.
[gzclient-18] [Err] [JointControlWidget.cc:393] Error advertising topic [/data://world/world/model/DeliveryRobot/plugin/slotcar/joint_cmd]

I can verify that the plugin exists at the directory /opt/ros/humble/lib/rmf_robot_sim_gz_plugins and I added the package rmf_robot_sim_gz_plugins to my package.xml as <exec_depend> but still nothing. How could I fix this?
